# Is there a way to delete a number from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a method that takes an already existing array and takes away a value (given by the user) from the array. I checked if the number is there but I don't know how to not include the unwanted number.

Also when I turn the code I get an error saying that I didn't initiate the result. What did I do wrong?

```
public static int[] deleteSingleValue(int[] myArray, Scanner kb){
if(kb == null || myArray == null || myArray.length < 1){
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("kb/myArray is null or myArray < 1");
   }
     
   System.out.print("Enter the number you want to remove: ");
   int num = kb.nextInt();
      
   int[] result;
      
   for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
      if(myArray[i] == num){
      int[] newArray = new int[myArray.length - 1];
         for(i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
         myArray[i] = newArray[i];
         }
      result = newArray;
      }
      else{
      System.out.println("Value NOT found");
      result = myArray;
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Edit* From the answers I've gotten it looks like I needed more than one variable to represent the index so it would skip over the unwanted number but not leave an index blank.

Rather than using 'i' for both myArray and new Array, I needed 'i' and another variable that increased if `num` was not equal to `myArray[i]`.

Thank you everyone for your help, I'll work on asking better questions.

Comment: You'll need to create a new array, shorter than the old one, and copy the numbers you want to keep. Or use a `List`. On your error, what value does `return result` have if the array is empty?

Comment: But you should work through some Java tutorials.

Comment: Debugging is a useful skill. If you want to become a software developer, or regularly develop software, it will be a necessary skill. Running the code in a debugger will allow you to set a breakpoint, and then run the code one-line-at-a-time while monitoring variables. For more tips, see [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Hint: Pay attention to `new array` and the inner `for` loop. And try to avoid altering the conents of `myArray`.

Comment: By the way, in more advanced Java: `int[] sans42 = Arrays.stream ( new int[] { 7 , 42 , 99 } ).filter ( ( int i ) -> i != 42 ).toArray ( );`

Answer (score 0):

> *"... when I turn the code I get an error saying that I didn't initiate the result. What did I do wrong? ..."*

A *null* value will not be inferred here, you'll need to initialize *result*.
In other words, the *[interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing))* has no way of knowing whether *result* is ever assigned a value.

> *"... I checked if the number is there but I don't know how to not include the unwanted number. ..."*

One approach is to trim *result* with the *[Arrays#copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int))* method.

```java
System.out.print("Enter the number you want to remove: ");
int i, j, num = kb.nextInt();

int[] result = new int[myArray.length];

for(i = 0, j = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    if(myArray[i] != num) result[j++] = myArray[i];
result = Arrays.copyOfRange(result, 0, j);
return result;
```

Or, count the number of values not equal to *num* first.

```java
System.out.print("Enter the number you want to remove: ");
int num = kb.nextInt(), x = 0;
for (int v : myArray) if (v != num) x++;

int[] result = new int[x];

for(int i = 0, j = 0, n = myArray.length; i < n; i++)
    if(myArray[i] != num) result[j++] = myArray[i];
return result;
```

Alternately, utilize the *[Arrays#copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int))*, *[copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int%5B%5D,int))*, and *[System#arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))* methods.
In this example I'm using *"a"*, instead of *"myArray"*, for readability.

```java
System.out.print("Enter the number you want to remove: ");
int num = kb.nextInt();

int[] b;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    if (a[i] == num) {
        b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, i + 1, a.length);
        a = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, i--);
        a = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + b.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, a.length - b.length, b.length);
    }
return a;
```

Or finally, use a *[stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)*.

```java
System.out.print("Enter the number you want to remove: ");
int num = kb.nextInt();

return IntStream.of(myArray)
                .filter(x -> x != num)
                .toArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

I hope my answer will help you.

```
public static int[] deleteSingleValue(int[] myArray, Scanner kb){
    if(kb == null || myArray == null || myArray.length < 1)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");
   
     
   System.out.print("Enter the number you want to remove: ");
   int num = kb.nextInt();
      
   int[] result = new int[myArray.length - 1];
   for(int i = 0, int j = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
      result[j]=myArray[i];
      if(myArray[i] != num) j++;
   }
   if(result.length != myArray.length) return result;
   return myArray;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is and what you changed.

Comment: There are some problems in Ainsley's code.

Comment: Of course there are. That is why Ainsley posted a question here. But, John Kugelman is pointing out a good answer should have explanation, not just code.

Comment: The O/P attempted to have the method handle the situation in which the target value is not found in `myArray`.  How will your code behave if the user enters a value that does not exist in `myArray`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To answer my question about how this code will work if the user enters a value that does not exist in `myArray`: This code will generate an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  And that is assuming the extra `int` is removed so it compiles cleanly.